# The size of PDF documents, how do I convert from millimeters to pixels using Spire.pdf?

Tags: pdf, size, converters

The size of PDF documents, how do I convert from millimeters to pixels using Spire.pdf?

```
    PdfDocument doc = new PdfDocument();
    doc.PageScaling = PdfPrintPageScaling.ActualSize;
    doc.LoadFromFile("myDocument.pdf");

    foreach (PdfPageBase page in doc.Pages)
    {
          //Result returns the pixel type. But I want to show in millimeters
         Console.WriteLine("PageSize: {0}X{1}", page.Size.Width, page.Size.Height);
    }
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The size of PDF pages is not expressed in pixels but in points.

```
1 inch = 72 points
1 inch = 25.4 mm
```

That leads to:

```
1 point = 0.352777778 mm
```